# Trying to call camel/javaee from springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, java-ee-7

I'm trying to call camel/java-ee/class (it's very long programs, so no time to convert) from a spring-boot.  So for now the solution is to just start with spring-boot and call the main class.

Here's the main application of springboot that will call the javaee/class, I tried the simple bean calling before, so this my latest test for I thought its about the proper call of bean, but unfortunately, even the proper calling of bean have the same error as the simple calling of bean,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        BeanAppService service = applicationContext.getBean(BeanAppService.class);
        service.callInitCamelJavaEE();
    }
}
```

Service interface,

```
public interface BeanAppService {
    
    void callInitCamelJavaEE() throws Exception;

}
```

Configuration,

```
@Configuration
public class BeanAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanAppService beanAppConfig() {
        return new BeanApp();
    }

}
```

BeanApp (this is the original main class with args in java/ee),

```
public class BeanApp implements BeanAppService {
    public BeanApp() {}
    
    protected <I extends SpongeRequest, O extends SpongeResponse> void createOperation(RestDefinition restDefinition, String operation,
    String operationDescription, Class<I> requestClass, String requestDescription, Class<O> responseClass,
    String responseDescription, BiFunction<I, Exchange, O> operationHandler) {
  restDefinition.post(operation).description(operationDescription).type(requestClass).outType(responseClass).param().name("body")
      .type(body).description(requestDescription).endParam().responseMessage().code(200).message(responseDescription)
      .endResponseMessage().route().id("sponge-" + operation).process(exchange -> {
        String requestBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
          logger.debug("REST API {} request: {}", operation, RestApiUtils.obfuscatePassword(requestBody));
        }
        try {
          setupResponse(operation, exchange,
              operationHandler.apply(getObjectMapper().readValue(requestBody, requestClass), exchange));
        } catch (Throwable processingException) {
          logger.info("REST API error", processingException);
          try {
            setupResponse(operation, exchange, apiService.createGenericErrorResponse(processingException, exchange));
          } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error("REST API send error response failure", e);
            throw e;
          }
        }
      }).endRest();
    }

    @Override
    public void callInitCamelJavaEE() throws Exception {
        try (CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext()) {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    restConfiguration().enableCORS(true).setPort("8080");
                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(6000000);
            camelContext.stop();
        }   
        
    }
```

The error,

```
StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then it's recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
Error starting CamelContext (camel-2) due to exception thrown: Failed to start route route1 because of null
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:122) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:270) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:157) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:115) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2889) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2702) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2665) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2431) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at ca.toronto.eis.dwork2.BeanApp.BeanAppApp.callMain(BeanAppApp.java:531) ~[main/:?]
    at ca.toronto.eis.dwork2.Dwork2Application.main(Dwork2Application.java:29) ~[main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestConsumerFactory in Registry or as a Component to use
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestEndpoint.createConsumer(RestEndpoint.java:602) ~[camel-rest-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.addServices(DefaultRoute.java:575) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:160) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:150) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:120) ~[camel-base-engine-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    ... 15 more
Apache Camel 3.7.0 (camel-2) is shutting down
Apache Camel 3.7.0 (camel-2) uptime 28ms
Apache Camel 3.7.0 (camel-2) is shutdown in 10ms
```

Anyone who have encountered this before?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like in the route builder you have not configured any route.

```
@Override
public void callInitCamelJavaEE() throws Exception {
    try (CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext()) {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                restConfiguration().enableCORS(true).setPort("8080");
            }
        });
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(6000000);
        camelContext.stop();
    }   
    
}
```

Assuming you are using Rest [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html) is How to configure a route in RouteBuilder using REST DSL

Comment: I debug the javaEE, on line [camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {] on the second execution, there's autowiredEnabled to true, the new one that call from springboot, it doesn't have it, that's why it's failing.  Not sure how to fix it.  But if I found it, I'll share it later.  Thanks [Ravi Shankar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11076053/ravi-shankar)

Comment: I was able to run camel 2 code on springboot, and I was able to use camel.springboot and it still works, although the code is camel 2 (like restDefinition).  Calling from springboot, with new class of the old java app, the main, I convert to just method and calling with new p, p.thatoldmethod(previously main).